# Linear independency implies linear independence of the gradients

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Consider a set of linear independent and homogeneous polynomials  $f_i:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ $i =1,\cdots,m$ and $m \leq n $.

I wonder if the Linear independency of $\{f_i\}$ implies the linear independence of its gradients $\{\nabla f_i\}$ evaluated at some point in $\mathbb{R}^n$?.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just do a simple example with functions of 1 variable $f(x)$ and $g(x)$.  You can always think of a function of 1 variable as a function of two variables $(x,y)$.

Comment: Yes, in this case $f(x,y) = x^k$ and $g(x,y)=x^l$ are linear  independent and their gradient $\nabla f$ and $\nabla g$ are linear independent  if $k \neq l$.

Comment: The gradient of a multivariate function is not an element of $\mathbb R^n$, it is  actually a vector field. So you mean linear independence in the vector space of vector fields?

Comment: Yes, the linear independence in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: You have not understood what I was saying. If you want to obtain an element of $\mathbb R^n$ from $\nabla f$, you need to evaluate it at some point. I do not think this is what you want...

Comment: Ok, my question then should be about the linear independency of  $\nabla f_i$ $i=1,\cdots,m$ at some point of $\mathbb{R}^n$ ?.

Comment: Do you know Euler's Theorem on homogeneous functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is of course false if we allow the polynomials to be constant, because the gradient of a constant is zero and thus linear dependent. But if we assume that all polynomials have positive degree, it is true as the following proof shows:

In characteristic zero, the gradient of a polynomial is zero if and only if the polynomial is constant.

Assume we have a linear combination $\sum a_i \nabla f_i=0$, then the polynomial $f := \sum a_if_i$ satisfies $\nabla f=0$, i.e. $f$ is constant. But as all $f_i$ have no constant term by assumption, we have that $f$ has no constant term either. This shows $f=0$, i.e. all $a_i=0$ by the linear independence of the $f_i$.

Comment: Dear @MooS many thanks for your answer.

Comment: The OP asked for linear independence of the gradients at a point, not in the vector space of polynomials.

Comment: He edited the question after I had answered...

Comment: If one evaluates at some point, you can not expect to linear independent vectors, for example take $n=1$...

Comment: What is the difference between the independence of the gradients at a point and in the vector space of polynomials. Are not equivalent?.

Comment: Definitely not equivalent. $x$ and $x^2$ are linear independent, but if you evaluate at $1$...

Comment: I read that according to the Wroskian matrix criterion, those cases in which the gradients $\{\nabla f_i \}$ evaluated at some point $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ of  linear independent polynomials  $f_i: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ are not linear independent, occur only at isolated points. Is correct?